# how to back to a specific java form?

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, button, back

I am building a JAVA project that content three forms first is to login second is for employee editing, and the third is to search

```
private void btnBackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    this.dispose();  
    myTools.Forms(new formSupervisor());
}
```

and the same process but instead of employee , the supervisor.
my question that i need to know in search form who is coming here Employee or Supervisor??   so i can return them to there form (Supervisor form or employee form)!
thanks.

Comment: I corrected the code formatting and some grammar. I'm still unclear on what the question means though, so I couldn't improve that.

Comment: The question is : i have many forms for example f1 f2 f3 and all f1 f2 f3 connected to f4 " when user pressing the button" . I want to know which form of those f1,f2,f3  refer to the current form f4.